# Plugin Posts 2 Posts : problems with the 'position' field

Tags: plugin-posts-to-posts

I must be a bit slow, I still have problems with the position field in the Posts-2-Posts plugin. If I set a position to each connection in a given post (say 1, 2 and 3) I don't understand how to display these connections in this order. I thought this would do the job :

```
$xxx = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'author',    
'p2p_orderby' => 'position',
'connected_order' => 'desc',
'connected_from' => get_the_ID()
) );
```

It doesn't. The position field is just not taken into account at all, even if I remove the line « 'p2p_orderby' => 'position' ». What do I do wrong ?

Comment: My code was flawed, please ignore this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it was actually 'connected_orderby' instead of 'p2p_orderby'.

Also, this can be done via drag-and-drop since version 0.9:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Connection-ordering